# Same table names, different schema issue in EDMX (Database first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, namespaces, entity-framework-5, schema

I have two tables with Same table name and different schema in the same database.
For example - **Vendor.Employee** and **Customer.Employee**

I am now adding EDMX file in my Class Library project under VS 2012. I am using EntityFramework 5.0.

Though it creates edmx files successfully without any issues, but it creates these entities with different names (like, Vendor.Employee is created as Employee entity, whereas Customer.Employee is created as Employee1 entity.

I understand its because both the classes are directly under same namespace, and so they get created with same names.
But is there any way (for example, giving namespaces per schema) or alternate to resolve this issue so we can have same table names.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Does anyone have at least a workaround?